# What are these partitons and can I delete them

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, boot-partition

I currently dual boot Windows 10 an Ubuntu, and I am getting ready to delete Windows.

The Ubuntu partitions that I know what they are are sda8,sda6, and sda7.

I assume sda4 is the main Windows partition.

What are sda1, sda2, sda3, and sda9, and can I delete them?

[image]

Comment: Don't delete the EFI partition (`sda2`) or your Ubuntu installation won't boot either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partitions with a key symbol next to them, are currently in use. These are the ones you should not delete.

You see a column "mount points" in your output. Each partition that has an entry in that column is currently connected to your running Ubuntu system. These are data partitions. The one connected to `/` is your system partition. So for sure, these are the ones you should not remove in order to keep your system functional.

One more partition is possibly being used by your system even if it is not mounted. That is the `swap` partition. Such partition can be used as overflow ram, and is never as such mounted. To check whether it is used in your system, run the `swapon` command. If `/dev/sda7` is used, you will see it mentioned in the output. If it is not in the output, it is not used and can be removed. Latest versions of Ubuntu do not use a swap partition anymore. They instead install a swap file, which you see in the output as `/swapfile`.

The other partitions can be removed without breaking your system. Of course, you do not want to loose user files. Thus, you need to make sure that any personal files that might be on these partitions are backed up to an external drive before you delete the partition.

- `sda1` is a recovery partition used for recovery if the installed Windows system has problems.
- `sda2` is the EFI partition, essential for booting your system
- `sda3` is a Microsoft Reserved Partition, used to store certain software components that previously used hidden sectors.
- `sda9` is a very small ntfs formatted partition, apparently with no specific purpose or use.

`sda3`, `sda4`, and `sda9` could be deleted. The freed contiguous space could be used for a new data partition.

Comment: Except EFI partition, as said in the comment above.

Comment: sda7 doesn’t have a mount point but it is in use as indicated by the key symbol. You don’t want to delete that unless converting to a swap file rather that a swap partition

Comment: swapon does list sda7, but I can leave that for another day because at least its used by Ubuntu in theory, not Windows

Answer (score 2):

The partitions are quite clearly described on your screenshot.

`sda1` is labelled "Recovery". Recovery partition allows to reinstall Windows and restore the computer to its factory default state. If you won't need Windows in the future, you can delete it.

`sda2` is the EFI partition which is needed to boot the operating systems in modern computers that use UEFI and not the legacy BIOS to boot the operating system. Don't delete it or your computer will not boot.

`sda3` is the [Microsoft reserved partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition) which is used for additional system data that may be used by Windows. If you won't need Windows in the future, you can delete it.

`sda4` is probably (as you suggest) the main Windows partition. To be sure, you can just mount in in Disks application and see what's on it.

I'm not sure what is the `sda9` partition - from the screenshot it looks that it is located at the very end of the disk. But because it is NTFS formatted, and flagged as `msftdata` (like `sda4`) it is probably also something used by Windows, maybe another recovery partition? Probably you can delete it.

`sda8` is a bit mysterious. Looks like something you created during Ubuntu installation (as it is ext4 formatted), but why isn't it mounted? Anyway, you said you know what this partition is, so no issue here.

`sda6` is a root filesystem of your Ubuntu installation. Of course you should not delete it.

`sda7` is a swap partition that your Ubuntu is currently using (it has a key icon next to its name, which indicates it is in use). Don't delete it as well. You can, however, assign swap space to a different partition or to a file on main Ubuntu partition, then it won't be needed anymore.